# Nested dictionary from nested list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have nested list like:.

```
[['A', 'A1'], ['A1', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'B1', 'B2'], ['B1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3',
 'B2', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'], ['C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'], ['C1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3','C2', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4','C3', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']]
```

I want to create the nested dictionary like:

```
{'A': {'A1': {'B': {'B1': {'b1': {}, 'b2': {}, 'b3': {}},
                    'B2': {'d1': {}, 'd2': {}, 'd3': {}, 'd4': {}}},
              'C': {'C1': {'a1': {}, 'a2': {}, 'a3': {}},
                    'C2': {'n1': {}, 'n2': {}, 'n3': {}, 'n4': {}},
                    'C3': {'x1': {}, 'x2': {}, 'x3': {}, 'x4': {}}}}}}
```

or:

```
{'A': {'A1': {'B': {'B1': ['b1', 'b2' 'b3', 'b4'],
                    'B2': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']},
              'C': {'C1': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
                    'C2': ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4'],
                    'C3': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']}}}
```

I have tried something like.

```
d = {}
for path in in nested_list:                                                
    current_dict = d                                                    
     for part in path:                                                            
          if part not in current_ dict:                                    
                current_dict [part]={}
```

but not getting desired result

Sample files

[1.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIYmb.jpg[2.txt(https://i.stack.imgur.com/brDUz.jpg)[3.txt(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaTwd.jpg)
[4.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Teecd.jpg)
[5.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcwLd.jpg)

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: i have tried something like.                                                         d {}.                                                                                             for path in in nested_list:.                                                       
    current_dict = d                                                    
     for part in path:.                                                                  
          if part not in current_ dict:.                                            
                current_dict [part]={}

Comment: The syntax of the desired outcome is not clear.  A dictionary is made from pairs, so `{'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'}` is not a dictionary.  It should at least say: `'C3' : {'x1': '', 'x2': '', 'x3': '', 'x4': ''}` or `'C3' : [ 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4' ]`.  Which is it?

Comment: @Speedymastro, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52959329/edit) and put that code in the question

Comment: @Kingsley `{'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'}` would be a `set`, so a dictionary of sets

Comment: C3' : {'x1': {}', 'x2': {} 'x3': {} 'x4':{}''}.

Comment: @Speedymastro is that a new requirement? if so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21216961) and put that into the question, not in comments please.

Comment: Or it can be it can be in this way also.                            C3' : [ 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4' ]

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT NOTE**: You have changed the input in your question after I gave this answer. The following solution pertains to your old input, where the list of lists was:

```
[['A', 'A1'], ['A1', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'B1', 'B2'], ['B1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
 ['B2', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'], ['C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'], ['C1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['C2', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4'], ['C3', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']]
```

Assuming your list of lists is stored in variable `l`, you can use the following `for` loop to construct the desire dictionary with a dictionary mapping `p` to keep track of the parent node for each key:

```
d = {}
p = {}
for k, *s in l:
    r = p.get(k, d)[k] = {i: {} for i in s}
    p.update({i: r for i in s})
```

`d` would become:

```
{'A': {'A1': {'B': {'B1': {'b1': {}, 'b2': {}, 'b3': {}},
                    'B2': {'d1': {}, 'd2': {}, 'd3': {}, 'd4': {}}},
              'C': {'C1': {'a1': {}, 'a2': {}, 'a3': {}},
                    'C2': {'n1': {}, 'n2': {}, 'n3': {}, 'n4': {}},
                    'C3': {'x1': {}, 'x2': {}, 'x3': {}, 'x4': {}}}}}}
```

To make leaf nodes a list, you can traverse the tree from the bottom up and use a set `m` to keep track of the child nodes so that you can use set difference to find all the top nodes to add to the main dictionary `d` in the end:

```
p = {}
m = set()
while l:
    k, *s = l.pop()
    p[k] = {i: p[i] for i in s} if all(i in p for i in s) else s
    m.update(s)
d = {i: p[i] for i in p.keys() - m}
```

`d` would become:

```
{'A': {'A1': {'B': {'B1': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
                    'B2': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']},
              'C': {'C1': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
                    'C2': ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4'],
                    'C3': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']}}}}
```

Comment: sorry i have given the wrong nested list i have corrected it i am really sorry

Comment: Your new input is a mess that mixes keys with values in the same sublists at different positions. Your old input at least puts the keys at the front of the sublists. Sorry but you should consult whoever that produces that input to fix the data structure rather than making band-aids over a structure that's fundamentally broken.

Comment: Ya i am stuck in this , i know pandas a little bit, if you know you can help me

Comment: The problem is really that the new input makes very little sense. For example, with the apparent rule to the data structure of your new input, `A1` can be interpreted as either a value to `A` or a separate key at the same level as `A`, so traversing the input from the top down is impossible. And traversing from the bottom up won't work either because there's no way to tell which among the items in `['B1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'B2', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']` are going to be keys.

Comment: You will therefore have to make two passes to find out which are keys and which are values, and even then there will be ambiguity. For example, `C2` is in the middle of two sublists in your new input. How then do you tell which sublist is supposed to represent `C2` as a value to another key, and which sublist is supposed to represent a key to the values that follow? You need to ask these hard questions to whoever that came up with this shakey data structure.

Comment: Actually i am reading this from the text file and storing in the list

Comment: I agree the new structure is a mess - @Speedymastro, perhaps you could share what the file format is.